# Remote chunking: can not instantiate from JSON object

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

I am using spring batch with remote chunking and i have the folowing problem:
when the master publih event in request queue using the json format (application/json), i have an exception when slave read this json event.

**Exception:**

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.ChunkRequest]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
>    at [Source: {"jobId":0,"items":[{"aaa":"11111","bbb":"22222","ccc":"33333"}],"stepContribution":{"readCount":0,"writeCount":0,"filterCount":0,"readSkipCount":0,"writeSkipCount":0,"processSkipCount":0,"exitStatus":{"exitCode":"EXECUTING","exitDescription":"","running":true},"skipCount":0,"stepSkipCount":0},"sequence":0}; line: 1, column: 2]

**RabbitMQ Message:**

> headers:
>   **TypeId**: org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.ChunkRequest
>   content_encoding:   UTF-8
>   content_type:   application/json
>   Payload
>   308 bytes
>   Encoding: string
>   {"jobId":0,"items":[{"aaa":"11111","bbb":"22222","ccc":"33333"}],"stepContribution":{"readCount":0,"writeCount":0,"filterCount":0,"readSkipCount":0,"writeSkipCount":0,"processSkipCount":0,"exitStatus":{"exitCode":"EXECUTING","exitDescription":"","running":true},"skipCount":0,"stepSkipCount":0},"sequence":0}

I use 'Jackson2JsonMessageConverter' as a message Converter for 'AmqpOutboundEndpoint' and 'AmqpInboundChannelAdapter'

Can you help me please?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`ChunkRequest` [doesn't support Jackson JSON serialization](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/b180c75ce0f6b38b6c6c3d37b5573a6f5c844a72/spring-batch-integration/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/integration/chunk/ChunkRequest.java) - it has no default CTOR.

It only supports Java Serialization; use a `SimpleMessageConverter` instead.

Or write a custom Jackson deserializer.

Comment: Thank you Gary for your quick replay. I spent a lot of time looking for a solution before writing to you, but without success.

Comment: I have an other related problem, when i use the default converter for remote chunking, the others rabbitMQ instances in the same application exchange the serialized messages too. How can produce and consume json message for the others? When i define an other rabbitMQ instance with the json converter, the problem is not resolved, and all my produced messages are the serialised messages. Can you help me please? Thank you.

Comment: You should really ask a new question rather than commenting on an old one. Use a [ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#_contenttypedelegatingmessageconverter) and set the content type header (you can choose a default converter for messages that don't have a content type header.